# Is there a way to change the background of a JButton multiple times in a single loop, with short pauses?

Tags: java, swing, background, synchronization, jbutton

I have a loop where a JButton background will change color multiple times in one loop with a pause in between. However, it waits the time of all pauses added together and then changed the color instantly.

here is a basic example of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            button.setBackground(Color.white);
            break;
        case 1:
            button.setBackground(Color.blue);
            break;
        case 2:
            button.setBackground(Color.black);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably a SwingTimer would be better here.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Yes, use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) (please check the tutorial link)